# What are the epis, monos, and extensions in the Freyd Envelope of a triangulated category?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, triangulated-categories, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal T$ be a triangulated category (or homotopy category of a stable $\infty$-category).

Recall that the *Freyd envelope* of $\mathcal T$ is an abelian category $\mathcal A$ which is universally equipped with a homological functor $\mathcal T \to \mathcal A$ (that is, exact functors out of $\mathcal A$ correspond bijectively to homological functors out of $\mathcal T$.

**Questions:** What are the monomorphisms, epimorphisms, and short exact sequences in the Freyd envelope $\mathcal A$ of a triangulated category $\mathcal T$? What are the isomorphisms?

In order for the question to be meaningful, let's recall a more explicit description of the Freyd Envelope. See Neeman's book on triangulated categories or Freyd's original paper *Stable Homotopy* (Proceedings of the Conference on Categorical Algebra LaJolla 1965).

- $\mathcal A$ can be identified with $mod(\mathcal T)$, the category of finitely-presentable functors $\mathcal T \to Ab$. As such, every object $a \in \mathcal A$ admits a presentation as the cokernel of a map $A'' \to A'$ with $A'', A' \in \mathcal T$. Moreover, the objects of $\mathcal T$ are projective in $\mathcal A$, so $\mathcal A$ can be described as a quotient of the arrow category of $\mathcal T$ by a congruence. In this description, the embedding $\mathcal T \to \mathcal A$ sends $A'$ to the map $0 \to A'$.
- Rotation of triangles in $\mathcal T$ ends up giving two related descriptions of $\mathcal A$. One represents $a \in \mathcal A$ as the kernel of a map $a \to A \to A''$ with $A,A'' \in \mathcal T$; the objects of $\mathcal T$ turn out to also be injective in $\mathcal A$, so we get a dual description to the above, and the embedding is $\mathcal T \to A$, $A'' \mapsto (A'' \to 0)$.
- There is also a "balanced" version, where we represent $a \in \mathcal A$ as the *image* of a map $A' \to A$ with $A',A \in \mathcal T$. This is Freyd's preferred presentation. Here two commutative squares $f,g: (A' \to A) \rightrightarrows (B' \to B)$ are equivalent in $\mathcal A$ iff the composite maps $A' \rightrightarrows B$ are equal. Here the embedding is $\mathcal T \to \mathcal A$, $A \mapsto (A = A)$.

Let's also recall a bit about kernels and cokernels

- In Freyd's *image* description, Freyd shows that every commutative square of the form $(A' \to A) \to (B' \to B)$ with $A \to B$ being the *identity* is a monomorphism. Dually, if $A' \to B'$ is an identity, then the map is an epimorphism. But I think there are more monos and epis.

In Freyd's description, I'd really like to know how to test if a commutative square in $\mathcal T$ represents a mono / epi / iso in $\mathcal A$, and how to test if a sequence of two commutative squares represents a short exact sequence in $\mathcal T$.